# Akka Streams, break tuple item apart?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http, google-cloud-pubsub

Using the [`superPool`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/request-level.html#flow-based-variant) from `akka-http`, I have a stream that passes down a tuple. I would like to pipeline it to the [Alpakka Google Pub/Sub connector](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/current/google-cloud-pub-sub.html). At the end of the HTTP processing, I encode everything for the pub/sub connector and end up with

```
(PublishRequest, Long) // long is a timestamp
```

but the interface of the connector is

```
Flow[PublishRequest, Seq[String], NotUsed]
```

One first approach is to kill one part:

```
  .map{ case(publishRequest, timestamp) => publishRequest }
  .via(publishFlow)
```

Is there an elegant way to create this pipeline while keeping the `Long` information?

**EDIT**: added my not-so-elegant solution in the answers. More answers welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My not-so-elegant solution is using a custom flows that recombine things:

```
val publishAndRecombine = Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit b =>

  val bc = b.add(Broadcast[(PublishRequest, Long)](2))
  val publisher = b.add(Flow[(PublishRequest, Long)]
    .map { case (pr, _) => pr }
    .via(publishFlow))
  val zipper = b.add(Zip[Seq[String], Long]). 

  bc.out(0) ~> publisher ~> zipper.in0
  bc.out(1).map { case (pr, long) => long } ~> zipper.in1

  FlowShape(bc.in, zipper.out)

})
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything inelegant about your solution using `GraphDSL.create()`, which I think has an advantage of visualizing the stream structure via the diagrammatic `~>` clauses.  I do see problem in your code.  For example, I don't think `publisher` should be defined by `add`-ing a flow to the builder.

Below is a skeletal version (briefly tested) of what I believe `publishAndRecombine` should look like:

```
val publishFlow: Flow[PublishRequest, Seq[String], NotUsed] = ???

val publishAndRecombine = Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit b =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  val bcast = b.add(Broadcast[(PublishRequest, Long)](2))
  val zipper = b.add(Zip[Seq[String], Long])

  val publisher = Flow[(PublishRequest, Long)].
    map{ case (pr, _) => pr }.
    via(publishFlow)
  val timestamp = Flow[(PublishRequest, Long)].
    map{ case (_, ts) => ts }

  bcast.out(0) ~> publisher ~> zipper.in0
  bcast.out(1) ~> timestamp ~> zipper.in1

  FlowShape(bcast.in, zipper.out)
})
```

Comment: Thanks Leo - this version is indeed cleaner! Just as a pointer, the `.map` on the `broadcast.out()` actually works :)

Comment: @ticofab, is there working sample code you can point me to, as I don't think method `map` is available for [akka.stream.Outlet](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/Shape.scala), which is what bcast.out(1) is.

Comment: Ah, the joys of implicits :) when you `import GraphDSL.Implicits._`, that `map` gets resolved to `def map[T]...` in `FlowOps`. Try out this working gist (akka 2.5.14): https://gist.github.com/ticofab/3d43f1c98aac65a40ca9227db9368e29

Comment: Thanks for the sample code @ticofab.  Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a much nicer solution for this which will be released in Akka 2.6.19 (see https://github.com/akka/akka/pull/31123).

In order to use the aformentioned `unsafeViaData` you would first have to represent `(PublishRequest, Long)` using `FlowWithContext`/`SourceWithContext`. `FlowWithContext`/`SourceWithContext` is an abstraction that was specifically designed to solve this problem (see https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-context.html). The problem being you have a stream with the data part that is typically what you want to operate on (in your case the `ByteString`) and then you have the context (aka metadata) part which you typically just pass along unmodified (in your case the `Long`).

So in the end you would have something like this

```
val myFlow: FlowWithContext[PublishRequest, Long, PublishRequest, Long, NotUsed] =
    FlowWithContext.fromTuples(originalFlowAsTuple) // Original flow that has `(PublishRequest, Long)` as an output

myFlow.unsafeViaData(publishFlow)
```

In contrast to [Akka Streams, break tuple item apart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51341038/akka-streams-break-tuple-item-apart/51344486#51344486), not only is this solution involve much less boilerplate since its part of akka but it also retains the materialized value rather than losing it and always ending up with a `NotUsed`.

For the people wondering why the method `unsafeViaData` has `unsafe` in the name, its because the `Flow` that you pass into this method cannot add,drop or reorder any of the elements in the stream (doing so would mean that the context no longer properly corresponds to the data part of the stream). Ideally we would use Scala's type system to catch such errors at compile time but doing so would require a lot of changes to akka-stream especially if the changes need to remain backwards compatibility (which when dealing with akka we do). More details are in the PR mentioned earlier.